# What are the different types life_cycle_state in databricks for job cluster

Tags: python, databricks

We are trying to get cluster life_cycle_state using API (api/2.0/jobs/runs/list) and we are able to get various values as below

```
RUNNING
PENDING
TERMINATED
INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Is there any other values apart from above values it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For the current 2.1 Jobs API

The life_cycle_states for `/api/2.1/jobs/runs/list` per Databricks API documentation are

```
"PENDING"
"RUNNING"
"TERMINATING"
"TERMINATED"
"SKIPPED"
"INTERNAL_ERROR"
"BLOCKED"
"WAITING_FOR_RETRY"
"QUEUED"
```

see the whole response and API doc at https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/jobs/listruns

### For the old 2.0 Jobs API

refer to the states here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/jobs-2.0-api#--runresultstate